# NSNull crashes my initWithDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, null, nsdictionary

I am parsing a JSON file.

After getting the NSDictionary, I parse the objects in the dictionary into an array of objects. However, for certain JSON files, I get NULL, which should be fine, but it crashes my app for those place where I am expecting something but getting null:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)boxDictionary {
 if ([self init]) {
  // ... 
  int numberOfBoxes = [[boxDictionary valueForKey:@"box_count"] intValue];
  int numberOfItemsInBoxes = [[boxDictionary valueForKey:@"box_items_count"] intValue];
        // ..
 }
 return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem seems to be that there is no intValue method on the NSNull that you're getting back from the call to valueForKey:.

You could add the intValue method, but what would you have it return for an NSNull?  0?  -1?

The code to do that would look something like this.

In MyNullExtensions.h:

```
@interface NSNull (integer)
-(int) intValue;
@end
```

And in MyNullExtensions.m:

```
#import "MyNullExtensions.h"

@implementation NSNull (functional)
-(int) intValue
{
    return -1;
}
@end
```

Later,
Blake.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` cannot be `nil`, so `intValue` doesn't have any way to tell you it can't get the `intValue` of a `nil` object. You need to check wether you got an object returned from `valueForKey:` before you ask for its `intValue`.

```
if ([boxDictionary valueForKey:@"box_count"])
    numberOfBoxes = [[boxDictionary valueForKey:@"box_count"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple test against NSNull before you call intValue. No need to extend NSNull object.

```
if ([rate valueForKey:@"value"]!=[NSNull alloc]) {

    // put your code here

}
```